pyenvで変わってしまったPython環境を元に戻したい
OSはWindows 11で、グローバルディレクトリにおいて、pyenvを使ってpython==3.9.6をインストールした後、もともと使っていたPython環境に戻そうとしているのですが、戻し方が分かりません。
pyenv global system を実行したところ、 "pyenv specific python requisite didn't meet. Project is using different version of python.Install python 'system' by typing: 'pyenv install system'" というメッセージが表示されています。
もともと使っていたPythonのversionが3.11.7だったので、3.11.0a7-win32をインストールしましたが解決しません。初心者で適当にいじくってしまった結果です。お分かりの方教えて頂きたいです。

この記事が参考になるかも。WindowsでPython環境を（再）構築する

pyenv の話をしていますか? pyenv-win の話をしていますか?

「もともと使っていたPython環境」というのは何でしょうか？

この記事によるとWindows向けにはsystemというのは無いようですが。pyenv-winのversionsにSystemを追加する あと他にこんな記事もあるようです。pyenvを使って任意のバージョンのPython環境を構築する, 【pyenv-win】pyenv のインストールと実行

元に戻すが「pyenv を維持したまま system の Python を指定する」「pyenv は削除して直接インストールした Python のみを使用する」等によって対応が変わってくると思います。

@quickquip 様、pyenv-winです

@merino 様、anacondaでインストールしたpythonをもともと使っていてそこでインストールしたpackageが全て使えず困っています

@cubick 様、pyenvの機能は残したいのですが、もともと使っていたpythonを使いたいです。そのためにpyenvを削除する必要があれば、削除します

皆さんご対応ありがとうございました。いちどシャットダウンしたら、元のpython,packageが使えました。
